# How can I turn integers into strings in a dict using Python?

Tags: python, api, dictionary

I'm creating a dictionary from the college scorecard API, but I'm having trouble joining integer queries to my dictionary (ie. "2015.student.size"). How would I do that in my code? I've tried "str() for f in", but that doesn't seem to work.

This is what I've written in Python so far:

```
import requests
import json

def main():
    url = 'https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.json'
    payload = {
        'api_key': "api_key_here",
        '_fields': ','.join([
            'school.name',
            'school.school_url',
            'school.city',
            'school.state',
            'school.zip',
        ]),
        'school.operating': '1',
        '2015.academics.program_available.assoc_or_bachelors': 'true',
        '2015.student.size__range': '1..',
        'school.degrees_awarded.predominant__range': '1..3',
        'school.degrees_awarded.highest__range': '2..4',
        'id': '240444',
    }
    data = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
    for result in data['results']:
        print(','.join(result.values()))

main()
```

What happens when I run the program:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/scripts$ python test.py
Madison,www.wisc.edu,University of Wisconsin-Madison,WI,53706-1380
```

When I add "print data":

```
{u'results': [{u'school.city': u'Madison', u'school.school_url': u'ww
w.wisc.edu', u'school.name': u'University of Wisconsin-Madison', u'sc
hool.state': u'WI', u'school.zip': u'53706-1380'}], u'metadata': {u'p
er_page': 20, u'total': 1, u'page': 0}}
```

Comment: Why do you need the integers to be strings? What did you try already? What happened? Did you get errors? If so what were they? If not, what was the output? How did the output differ from what you want?

Comment: I don’t understand what you are asking. `'1..'` is not a number?

Comment: could you please edit to add an example of what the `data` json looks like

Comment: If you are want to print the dictionary so you can check if it is correct, you should just do `print(data)` or `print(data['results'])` or `print(result)` in your for loop. Don't make this more difficult than you need to.

Comment: This is mainly for the "join" dictionary. When I added "2015.student.size", I received an error stating the program was expecting a string, not an integer.

Comment: Why do you need to use `join()` here at all? See my previous comment about easier ways to print the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making this more difficult than necessary. Instead of the for loop, you can do

```
print(data)
```

Or if you want each dictionary from the list to be on its own line, instead of

```
print(','.join(result.values()))
```

Just do

```
print(result)
```

Comment: Welp, that cleared it up. I think I was making it more complicated than necessary. I got one more request: After I get all the JSON data necessary, I need to parse all the dictionary information in this code (ie. 'University of Wisconsin-Madison' for school.name, 'WI' for school.state, etc) into my HTML file. I've tried doing <h2 data-bind="school.state"></h2> in the HTML document, but nothing pops up.

Comment: @Hegemon1984 How are you generating the HTML? You should post a new question. (Most likely, you just need to print the value directly from the dictionary, rather than the literal string `"school.state"`.)

Comment: Got it. By printing the value directly from the dictionary, do you mean creating a script tag, doing a for loop through results and printing it?

Comment: @Hegemon1984 In order to get into more details, you need to answer my question: how are you generating the HTML? It would be best for you to post a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Generally, I generate the HTML by running my Python program via Vagrant in which the HTML template is generated as well as the Python file.

Comment: @Hegemon1984 You should ask a new question and show example Python code for generating the HTML